# 4×4 Tic-Tac-Toe in C

Tags: c, game, tic-tac-toe

While trying to teach myself C, I decided to take a stab at writing this Tic-Tac-Toe program on a 4x4 board. It will be great if somebody could review it and let me know of some ways of refining this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct {
    int xpos;
    int ypos;
} BRDPOS;

void printBoard(int brd_size,char board[][brd_size]){
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0;i < brd_size;i++){
        for(j = 0;j < brd_size;j++){
            if(j == 0) printf("| ");
            printf("%c |",(char)board[i][j]);
            if(j == (brd_size - 1)){
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }   
}

BRDPOS getPosition(int brd_size,char board[][brd_size]){
    //Enter Positions X and Y
    BRDPOS pos;
    int x,y;
    do{
        printf("Enter the x-position:");
        scanf("%d",&x);
        printf("\nEnter the y-position:");
        scanf("%d",&y);
        printf("\n");               
    }while(board[x][y] != ' ');
    pos.xpos = x;
    pos.ypos = y;
    return pos;
}

void updateBoard(int brd_size,char board[][brd_size],BRDPOS pos,int player){
    if(player == 0){
        board[pos.xpos][pos.ypos] = 'X';
    }else{
        board[pos.xpos][pos.ypos] = 'O';
    }
}

int isWinningPosition(BRDPOS position,int brd_size,char brd[][brd_size],int player){
    char posChar = (player == 0)? 'X':'Y';
    int xPos = position.xpos;
    int yPos = position.ypos;
    char yStatus = brd[0][0];
    char majDiag = brd[0][0];
    char minDiag = brd[0][brd_size-1];
    int xstatus = 0;
    int ystatus = 0;
    int majdiag = 0; 
    int mindiag = 0;
    int i,j,k,l;
    for(i=0;i< brd_size;i++){
        if(brd[xPos][yPos] == brd[xPos][i]){
            xstatus = 1;
        }else{
            xstatus = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    //Check if the horizontal has the same characters
    for(j=0;j<brd_size;j++){
        if(brd[xPos][yPos] == brd[j][yPos]){
            ystatus = 1;
        }else{
            ystatus = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    //Check if the major diagonal has the same characters
    if(xPos == yPos){
        for(k=0;k < brd_size;k++){
            if(majDiag == brd[k][k]){
                majdiag = 1;
            }else{
                majdiag = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //Check if the minor diagonal has the same characters
    if(xPos == (brd_size - 1 - yPos)){
            for(l = 1;l < brd_size;l++){
                if(minDiag == brd[l][(brd_size-1) - l]){
                    mindiag = 1;
                } else {
                    mindiag = 0;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
    return xstatus|ystatus|majdiag|mindiag; 
}

int main()
{
    //Flag to indicate the current player 0 for A, 1 for B. Default to A
    int player = 0;
    //Flag to indicate the winner, -1 for no winner, 0 for A, 1 for B
    int winner = -1;
    //Counter to indicate the total number of turns
    int counter = 0;
    //Tic-Tac-Toe board
    char board[4][4];
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0;i<4;i++){
        for(j = 0;j<4;j++){
            board[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
    //Keep iterating until a winner is found and the cell count is less than 16 
    while((winner == -1) && (counter < 16)){
        //Print the tic-tac-toe board
        printBoard(4,board);
        //Ask position to place the X for player 1
        //getPosition keeps asking for the position until a legal position has been entered
        printf("Enter positions for PlayerA:\n");
        BRDPOS positionA = getPosition(4,board);
        //Update board with positionA
        printf("Updating the board:\n");
        updateBoard(4,board,positionA,0);
        //Check if the updated position is a winning position
        if(isWinningPosition(positionA,4,board,0)){
            //Mark player A as the winner
            printf("Marking player A as the winner \n");
            winner = 0;
            break;
        }
        //update the move counter
        counter++;
        //print updated board
        printBoard(4,board);
        //Ask position to place the 'O' for player 2
        printf("Enter position for PlayerB:\n");
        BRDPOS positionB = getPosition(4,board);
        //Update board with positionB
        updateBoard(4,board,positionB,1);
        //Check if the updated position is a winning position       
        if(isWinningPosition(positionB,4,board,1)){
            winner = 1;
            break;
        }
        //update the move counter
        counter++;
    }
    //print the final board configuration
    printBoard(4,board);
    switch(winner){
        case -1: printf("The game is a draw!\n");
             break;
        case 0: printf("Player 1 has won the game\n");
             break;
        case 1: printf("Player 2 has won the game\n");
            break;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `struct` name should only *start* with an uppercase letter.  Having the entire name in caps makes it appear as a macro.

Comment: Does this code work as intended?  The board isn't showing up properly for me when I run this.

Comment: @syb0rg Works for me.

Comment: @200_success Odd.  I'll work with it anyways I guess :P

Comment: @syb0rg It crashes [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99c6a6e7f2432c66).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### General:

I myself am writing a [Tic-Tac-Toe game of sorts](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1471), so I am go to try to not give my code away too much.  For a self-taught beginning C programmer, this code looks good. However, it looks like you were over thinking things a bit based on how long your code is.

---

### What you did well on:

- You kept your dependencies at a minimum (for the most part).
- You attempt to use comments to describe what your thought process is and how the program works.
- You used `typedef` with your `struct` properly.
- You used a `switch` instead of multiple `if-else` test conditions (very good!).

---

### Things you could improve on:

- You unnecessarily `#include <stddef.h>`.
- You aren't using the characters that correspond with a Tic-Tac-Toe game.

  > ```
  >    char posChar = (player == 0)? 'X':'Y';
  > ```

  I don't see any reason to not use the `X`'s and `O`'s.  We want to be as user-experience friendly as possible to lowering the initial learning curve for first time users.

  ```
  char posChar = (player == 0) ? 'X' : 'O';
  ```
- Your name of the `typedef struct` is not how the usual programmer would name it.

  > ```
  >    typedef struct {
  >        int xpos;
  >        int ypos;
  >    } BRDPOS;
  > ```

  Right now you are using the naming standards that coincide with naming a macro.  Here is how I would name a similar struct.

  ```
  typedef struct
  {
      int xPos;
      int yPos;
  } BoardPosition;
  ```
- You have some unused variables: `posChar`, `yStatus`, and `player`.  Get rid of them.
- I would `#define` your board size at the top.

  ```
  #define ROWS 4
  #define COLS 4
  ```
- You always set some variables in a function to your `struct` values.

  ```
   int xPos = position.xpos;
   int yPos = position.ypos;
  ```

  I'm not seeing the purpose of using these local variables at all.  I would remove them and use the direct `struct` values in their place.
- Initialize variables in your `for` loop, not outside of them.<sup>(C99)</sup>

  ```
  for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
  ```
- Your comments are sporadic.  Also, some areas have too many comments.

  > ```
  >    //Ask position to place the X for player 1
  >    //getPosition keeps asking for the position until a legal position has been entered
  >    printf("Enter positions for PlayerA:\n");
  >    BRDPOS positionA = getPosition(4,board);
  > ```

  Here is an example of where I think you are saying too much with your comments.  Some code can speak for itself.  However, in other areas you have no comments at all.

  > ```
  >    return xstatus|ystatus|majdiag|mindiag;
  > ```

  Some people may not know what the bitwise operator `|` does.  You should comment more in areas like these that may be more confusing to newer developers.
- You could use the function `puts()` in place of your `printf()`.

  > ```
  >    printf("Enter position for PlayerB:\n");
  > ```

  Using `puts()` is a bit better in my mind.  Then you don't have to worry about the `\n` character at the end.

  ```
  puts("Enter position for PlayerB: ");
  ```

Comment: btw. out of interest, does it make sense to play this kind of 4x4 tic tac toe game? I think this is very easy not to let someone win here. (For learning purposes I know it's ok, I am asking for the sake of playing)

Comment: @hanalbuseltes I think it makes sense to play, sure.

Comment: @syb0rg - Thanks for taking the time to provide a detailed review. Learned quite a bit from your and 200_success's review.

Answer (score 7):

I see no major memory-handling or parameter-passing errors, which is pretty good for a self-taught C novice.

---

First, let the compiler do the reviewing…

> ```
> $ clang -Wall -g -o tictactoe cr41304.c 
> cr41304.c:47:10: warning: unused variable 'posChar' [-Wunused-variable]
>     char posChar = (player == 0)? 'X':'Y';
>          ^
> cr41304.c:50:10: warning: unused variable 'yStatus' [-Wunused-variable]
>     char yStatus = brd[0][0];
>          ^
> cr41304.c:103:9: warning: unused variable 'player' [-Wunused-variable]
>     int player = 0;
>         ^
> 3 warnings generated.
> ```

`yStatus` is particularly bad: having variables named `yStatus` and `ystatus` in the same function is confusing.

---

The user experience could use some polishing.

- The first column is inexplicably wider than the others.
- Your terminology is inconsistent: "PlayerA"/"PlayerB" when prompting *vs.* "Player 1"/"Player 2" when announcing the winner.  (In your code, you also call them players 0 and 1.)  I suggest "Player X" and "Player O".
- This statement appears to be left over from development:

  ```
  printf("Marking player A as the winner \n");
  ```
- "Row" and "column" would be clearer than "x-position" and "y-position".
- Zero-based numbering is unusual.  To eliminate ambiguity, label the rows and columns when printing the board.

---

You fail to check the return value from `scanf()` for <kbd>EOF</kbd>.  If <kbd>EOF</kbd> is encountered, it goes into an infinite loop.

---

Your main loop contains copy-and-pasted code for each player.  You should be able to restructure your code to avoid repeating yourself.

Your functions all take their parameters in a different order.  Try to be consistent.

`updateBoard()` could be shorter.

```
void updateBoard(int brd_size, char board[][brd_size], BRDPOS pos, int player) {
    assert(player == 0 || player == 1);
    board[pos.xpos][pos.ypos] = "XO"[player];
}
```

`isWinningPosition()` could also be shorter.  Avoid using so many variables.  Declare your dummy variables in a tighter scope (which you can do since you're using C99).  Return early as soon as you find a win.  I believe your `//Check if the horizontal has the same characters` comment is wrong as well — that loop is actually checking for a vertical win.

```
int isWinningPosition(BRDPOS position,int brd_size,char brd[][brd_size],int player){
    int xPos = position.xpos;
    int yPos = position.ypos;

    // Check for horizontal win
    int win = 1;
    for (int y = 0; win && (y < brd_size); y++) {
        if (brd[xPos][yPos] != brd[xPos][y]) {
            win = 0;
        }
    }
    if (win) return 1;

    // Check for vertical win
    win = 1;
    for (int x = 0; win && (x < brd_size); x++) {
        if (brd[xPos][yPos] != brd[x][yPos]) {
            win = 0;
        }
    }
    if (win) return 1;

    // Check if the major diagonal has the same characters
    win = (xPos == yPos);
    for (int x = 0; win && (x < brd_size); x++) {
        if (brd[xPos][yPos] != brd[x][x]){
            win = 0;
        }
    }
    if (win) return 1;

    // Check if the minor diagonal has the same characters
    win = (xPos == (brd_size - 1 - yPos));
    for (int x = 0; win && (x < brd_size); x++) {
        if (brd[xPos][yPos] != brd[x][(brd_size-1) - x]){
            win = 0;
        }
    }
    return win;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess you could change all this code:

```
  while((winner == -1) && (counter < 16)){
        //Print the tic-tac-toe board
        printBoard(4,board);
        //Ask position to place the X for player 1
        //getPosition keeps asking for the position until a legal position has been entered
        printf("Enter positions for PlayerA:\n");
        BRDPOS positionA = getPosition(4,board);
        //Update board with positionA
        printf("Updating the board:\n");
        updateBoard(4,board,positionA,0);
        //Check if the updated position is a winning position
        if(isWinningPosition(positionA,4,board,0)){
            //Mark player A as the winner
            printf("Marking player A as the winner \n");
            winner = 0;
            break;
        }
        //update the move counter
        counter++;
        //print updated board
        printBoard(4,board);
        //Ask position to place the 'O' for player 2
        printf("Enter position for PlayerB:\n");
        BRDPOS positionB = getPosition(4,board);
        //Update board with positionB
        updateBoard(4,board,positionB,1);
        //Check if the updated position is a winning position       
        if(isWinningPosition(positionB,4,board,1)){
            winner = 1;
            break;
        }
        //update the move counter
        counter++;
    }
```

to only this:

```
  while((winner == -1) && (counter < 16)){
        //Print the tic-tac-toe board
        printBoard(4,board);
        //Ask position to place the X for player 1
        //getPosition keeps asking for the position until a legal position has been entered
        printf("Enter positions for PlayerA:\n");
        BRDPOS position = getPosition(4,board);
        //Update board with positionA
        printf("Updating the board:\n");
        updateBoard(4,board,position,counter%2);// change
        //Check if the updated position is a winning position
        if(isWinningPosition(position,4,board,counter%2)){// change
            winner = counter%2;// change
            break;
        }

        counter++;
    }
```

the changes occur due to using: `counter%2`

In the initial code, you had *two* very similar pieces of code, with only difference that once you would pass 0 and other times 1 to certain functions depending on who was playing. You were deducing who was playing sort of manually, which is ok, this is a consecutive game - at first one player plays, at the next step another player. But this consecutive nature you can exploit also using the % operator. You already had `counter` variable. Do it modulo 2, and once you get 1 and other time 0. Now you can use `counter%2` instead of manually passing 1 and 0s.

```
0%2=0
1%2=1
2%2=0
3%2=1
4%2=0
....
etc.
```

Comment: Could you explain *why* you would change it?  **Show** the OP your changes.

Comment: @syb0rg: I mentioned where, I just don't know how to format in code so that it is more visible... as to why,I guess less code/redundancy

Comment: Ahh, much better.  Upvote given.